# Use Redis for communication between nodes

Tags: c++, node.js, redis

I am working on an application which consists of 2 layers: The GUI built in Electron and the "backend" built in C++ running in the background. The GUI needs to be able to (amongst other things such as streaming data) send and request data to and from the backend for configuration purposes. For communication Redis is being used, mainly for its pub/sub capability.

What would be the preferred way to request and send data from/to the backend? I came up with the following ideas but I'm not sure if any of these are the way to go.

1. Publish value on a `configuration` channel and handle the request via switch case. E.g. `configuration.set_sensor_frequency` is handled by a `set_sensor_frequency(value)` function in the backend.
2. Write the configuration to `configuration.sensor_frequency` on the redis server and listen to the `set` event on the backend and react accordingly. But this kinda seems like method 1 but more complicated.
3. Like method 2, write the config to the redis server and periodically check (every few cycles or so) in the backend whether the value has been updated
4. Something else. Please elaborate.

Comment: Why did you choose Redis? Not MQ (Rabbit for example) or sockets or smth else?

Comment: @ARalkov We were using our own socket implementation which ended up taking the form of a message broker. Instead of developing that we decided between Redis and ZeroMQ and eventually switched to Redis. It was simple and there was a single node which was the message broker. Extensibility was also easy since every other client could simply connect to the Redis server. I am looking into Rabbit now.